# Issues with adding a new Java project to a Github location

Tags: git

I have been having issues with adding a Java project to my git area. I have tried the following commands in steps:

```
git init # To my Eclipse Java project folder
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/manmedia/MyProjectFolder.git
git commit -a -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

I have viewed similar questions on StackOverflow and tried to apply the solutions suggested, but nothing worked. I am constant getting the following error message:

```
remote: Repository not found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/manmedia/MyProjectFolder.git' not found.
```

I am fairly new to Git and trying to understand this beast (very inconvenient compared to SVN and CVS, I must say). Do I actually need to be on Github.com to create the repository and then fork it out or can I do it directly from my Windows command prompt?

Comment: You should `git remote add`, not `git remote set-url` here

Comment: It doesn't matter, gives me the same thing. I actually tried 'add` before 'set-url'. I found the set-url bit somewhere in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I actually need to be on Github.com to create the repository

Yes, you need to create an *empty* Git repo on GitHuhb first.

> and then fork it out

No fork or clone needed then. The rest of your commands executed locally should work.

I would just add your GitHub login in the url:

```
git remote set-url origin https://<yourLogin>@github.com/manmedia/MyProjectFolder.git
```

Make sure you did first (at least before the first commit) a:

```
git config --global user.name <yourLogin>
git config --global user.email <yourEmail>
```

Comment: I have actually gone to Github.com to create my repo first. and now I have cloned it to my local project folder. I just need to add additional files, commit, and finally, push 'em out. Thanks for not considering this problem as silly :)

Comment: @ha9u63ar no problem, this is a valid question. You can also consider the step 10 of https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/10.

Comment: Github shows the URL to use on the repository page.